# actions on google--unable to use app.tell to give response from JSON

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to get my webhook to return a parsed JSON response from an API.  I can log it on the console, but when I try to use `app.tell`; it gives me:  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'tell' of undefined.`  I am basically able to successfully get the data from the API, but I'm not able to use it in a response for some reason.  Thanks for the help!

```
  [Actions.API_TRY] () {

var request = http.get(url2, function (response) {
// data is streamed in chunks from the server
// so we have to handle the "data" event
var buffer = "",
    data,
    route;

response.on("data", function (chunk) {
    buffer += chunk;
});

response.on("end", function (err) {
    // finished transferring data
    // dump the raw data
    console.log(buffer);
    console.log("\n");
    data = JSON.parse(buffer);
    route = data.routes[0];

    // extract the distance and time
    console.log("Walking Distance: " + route.legs[0].distance.text);
    console.log("Time: " + route.legs[0].duration.text);



    this.app.tell(route.legs[0].distance.text);
});
});


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me to be more of a JavaScript scoping issue than anything else. The error message is telling you that app is undefined. Often in Actions, you find code like yours embedded in a function which is defined **inside** the intent handler which is passed the instance of your Actions app (SDK or Dialog Flow).

Comment: I agree. Using `this` is going to create some ambiguity as I don't think it refers to the thing you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I ended up separating the action from the API call and that solved it.

Comment: Still not doing what I want.  I need to be able to somehow do the API call inside the mapped intent because I need to use the zip code information from the user.  Any ideas on how I can do the API call inside of [Actions.API_TRY]?